# Object alpha masking in 3d model view

Tags: android, rajawali

I am doing alpha masking using rajawali library.

I have make some objects transparent using alpha masking. all objects are visible from viewing it from front but only one object is not visible from front after alpha masking it.

And one more thing that, as i rotate whole object it is visible from back.

My code for transparency is like below:

```
BaseObject3D abc = mObjectGroup.getChildByName("Mesh103_Group_22_5_Group17_Model");
abc.setMaterial(new SimpleMaterial(AMaterial.ALPHA_MASKING));
abc.addTexture(mTextureManager.addTexture(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.img)));
abc setTransparent(true);
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using below code my work done.

```
abc.backSided(true);
abc.doubleSided(true)
```